# Identity matrix using Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, identity

The following code give the identity matrix of any size the user wish it to be:

```
program identitymatrix

  real, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: I
  character:: fmt*8
  integer :: ms, j

 print*,'the size of the matrix is?'
 read*,ms

  allocate(I(ms,ms))
  I = 0                           ! Initialize the array.
  forall(j = 1:ms) I(j,j) = 1     ! Set the diagonal.

  ! I is the identity matrix, let's show it:

  write (fmt, '(A,I2,A)') '(', ms, 'F6.2)'
  ! if you consider to have used the (row, col) convention, 
  ! the following will print the transposed matrix (col, row)
  ! but I' = I, so it's not important here  
  write (*, fmt) I(:,:)

  deallocate(I)

end program identitymatrix     (the end of the code )
```

I am a bit confused about these two code  pieces ?

```
write (fmt, '(A,I2,A)') '(', ms, 'F6.2)'

write (*, fmt) I(:,:)
```

What does `(A,I2,A)` do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`'(A,I2,A)'` is a *format specification*; this one specifies a character field of sufficient length to hold the variable passed to it, followed by a 2-digit integer (field), followed by another character field which will be as long as the variable passed.

This statement

```
write (fmt, '(A,I2,A)') '(', ms, 'F6.2)'
```

uses that format specification to write another format specification into the character variable `fmt`.  If, at run-time, `ms` has the value `4`, `fmt` will become `'(4F6.2)'`. This, in turn, is used to format the next write statement:

```
write (*, fmt) I(:,:)
```

This is the standard Fortran approach to creating output formats at run-time.

Comment: why when I change the digit integer to any value beside '2' I get an error at run-time.

Comment: You're probably not using the edit descriptor to write a 1- or 2-digit integer.  Try experimenting: use simple write statements to write to the console varying both the width of the field and the size of the integer.

Comment: *Late comment, but may help a bit*. You can also use the `G0` edit descriptor instead of `I2`. It was introduced in Fortran 2008, see section 10.7.5 of the standard. With this, no need to worry about the actual width of the integer printed. It's recognized by the Intel and GNU compilers, but not yet by the Absoft compiler (as of Absoft 16.0.1).